# how to generate Master Key and MasterSalt in esapi

Tags: java, owasp, esapi

I want to generate Master Key and MasterSalt in esapi for my application. 
Default are

```
Encryptor.MasterKey=7AXyrRttFnPJHgzD/lTntA==
Encryptor.MasterSalt=tBp5pH+wXKHoICzUMLvnLQcncKE=
```

I tried to generate according to mentioned documentaion but m getting this error

```
E:\OWASP\esapi-2.1.0-dist>java esapi-2.1.0.jar -jar org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI
Error: Could not find or load main class esapi-2.1.0.jar
```

Please guide me if I am doing any wrong. Steps will be helpfull. OR Is there any other way to generate these key? Please help, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

There's a UNIX (bash) shell script in

> src/examples/scripts/setMasterKey.sh

that will show you how to do this. If your are running under Windows, it should work with Cygwin. Otherwise, you will have to translate it to a DOS script yourself.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, you must write:
java -jar esapi-2.1.0.jar org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI

The -jar command introduces the jar containing the code to be executed.

Comment: the output is "no main manifest attribute, in esapi-2.1.0.jar"

Answer (score 0):

In **ESAPI version 2.1.0**, the [JavaEncryptor](https://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-java/source/browse/trunk/src/org/owasp/esapi/reference/JavaEncryptor.java?r=364) class has moved to the crypto package. It used to be located in the `org.owasp.esapi.reference` package. Now it is one level deeper in `org.owasp.esapi.reference.crypto`. Plus, be sure to reference the necessary jars this tool depends on. The libs directory is part of the esapi-2.1.0-dist download.

At the *nix command line:

```
java -classpath esapi-2.1.0.jar:libs/* org.owasp.esapi.reference.crypto.JavaEncryptor
```

For windows, remember to replace the colon with a semi colon.

Comment: where's the official download page for ESAPI? i can't seem to find it anywhere on owasp.org.